# Should I have my web application access AWS services through the front-end or back-end?

Tags: python, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am developing a Web Application with Angular as my front-end and Python (Flask) as the back-end. My application also utilizes several AWS services and is hosted on Azure.

One function of my application is to

1. Take an audio file from user
2. Put it in a S3 bucket (AWS)
3. Transcribe it (using Amazon Transcribe) and get result
4. Process the resultant text and return the results to the user

Currently, I am performing steps 1 and 2 using Angular and steps 3 and 4 using Python. So part of AWS services are being accessed by Angular and others by Python.

My question is that should I

- Have only Angular (front-end) interact with all AWS services directly? (so Python only does step 4)
- Or have only Python (back-end) interact with all AWS services? (so Angular only does step 1)
- Or some combination of the two?

I am looking for an answer preferably in terms of better design practice, security, performance and ease. Thank you.

Comment: "From Angular" means that you're giving some sort of API access to the browser, and by extension to any user who cares about poking around the code a bit. You need to be very careful not to give users too much access to your API this way. If they shouldn't have a specific power, don't expose that power to the frontend.

Comment: you should look at the AWS serverless architecture (https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/) where a website can be hosted on s3, which has angular call API gateway, which calls a lambda function which uses the AWS SDK to access the AWS services to return a response/error